# Unobtrusive way testing JavaScript with Cucumber?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, cucumber

what do you prefer for testing JavaScript apps using Cucumber?

I never did it before - I only used Webrat for testing plain html.

I have tried Selenium, but it frustrated me and I didn't find any good documentation about Cucumber in combination with Selenium.

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Around here we let webrat drive selenium for most of the operations. But it's still very fresh technology so be prepared to dig around in the code and debugger a bit.

Answer (score 4):

Check out [Capybara](http://github.com/jnicklas/capybara). It's a drop-in replacement for Webrat, but it lets you drive Firefox via Selenium for testing Javascript code (e.g. AJAX calls).

Answer (score 0):

Documentation:
https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Setting-up-Selenium

There are also resources on that wiki for various flavors of Watir.